# Allow user to enter 4 characters at max before decimal and 2 numbers after decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a text box with fixed decimal point - "0.00".

When the user tabs out from the previous textbox, it should come to the beginning of this text box and user can enter the max amount to 4 characters before decimal and after decimal they can enter only characters.

I have tried below things -

1. Tried using regex - `^\d{2}(\.\d{2})?$` in MVC using Data Annotations but not working as it is not restricting the characters in the page. So I thought to go to Javascript solution.
2. In JS I have used -

In Key up event I have used below code -

```
if (loadDecimal > 0 && loadAmount.length > loadDecimal + 1) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().toString().substring(0, loadDecimal + 3));
    }
```

which acts in weird way. It allows me to enter the first character and then the controls goes to last and then it allows to me add characters after 2 decimals. However, it will be removed after entering the numbers.

Let me know if any one has any solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native `min`, `max`, and `step` attributes on a regular `<input type="number">`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numeric-input" type="number" min="0" max="9999" step="0.01">
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply !!  My client wanted free text box sort of control so we went ahead with TextBox control in MVC. Unfortunately this solution does not work in my project.